# Doesn't "first-of-type" work as a content-select value?

Tags: html, css-selectors, web-component, shadow-dom

Why doesn't "footer text1" show in the below code?
My browser is Chrome 36.0.1985.125

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <h2>Eric</h2>
        <h2>Bidelman</h2>
        <div>Digital Jedi</div>
        <h4>footer text1</h4>
        <h4>footer text2</h4>
    </div>

    <template id="sdom">
        <header>
            <content select="h2"></content>
        </header>
        <section>
            <content select="div"></content>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <content select="h4:first-of-type"></content>
        </footer>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var container = document.querySelector('#example');
        var root = container.createShadowRoot();
        var t = document.querySelector('#sdom');
        var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
        root.appendChild(clone);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should. The spec says it accepts any compound selector, and `h4:first-of-type` is certainly a valid compound selector.

Comment: Oh...my browser is Chrome 36.0.1985.125 by the way.

Comment: Seems like none of the pseudo-classes work (tried: first, first-child, first-of-type, last, last-child, nth-child).

Comment: Thank you. I reported this at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402234&thanks=402234&ts=1407592959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This was just a bug.</strike> 

This was working as intended.
Thank you all.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402234&thanks=402234&ts=1407592959

http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#satisfying-matching-criteria